# Is there such a equivalence ralation existing on a set of natural number N?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The corresponding quotient(or the set of equivalence classes) of this relation is

{ {1}, {2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10}, {11,12,13,14,15},...}

We thought of lots of answers at today's class but no one is correct...I am confused now... Is there such a relation existing on set N?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  In particular, what "no one of them is correct".  What does "correct" mean in this context?  Does it mean, "not what the lecturer had in mind?"  Or what?

Comment: It just simply means we did not come up with a relation which matches this corresponding quotient. Sorry for making you confused.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Consider this relation: $m\sim n$ when one of these conditions occur:

- $m,n\in\{1\}$;
- $m,n\in\{2,3\}$;
- $m,n\in\{4,5,6\}$;
- $m,n\in\{7,8,9,10\}$;
- $\vdots$

Comment: I cannot get the point of your answer. Could you please explain more details about it? Thanks!

Comment: I would love to, but I really cannot see how can I possibly provide more detais. Don't you understand the meaning of $m\sim n$?

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers are equivalent when they have the same least triangle number strictly greater than them. Since$$T_{k-1}\le n<T_k\iff(2k-1)^2\le 8n<(2k+1)^2\iff k-1\le\frac{\sqrt{8n}-1}{2}<k,$$your relation has $m\sim n$ iff $\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8m}-1}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n}-1}{2}\right\rfloor$.